# Positioning :after-pseudo behind text in a link

Tags: html, css, z-index, pseudo-element

I was wondering if it's possible to position the z-index of a :after-pseudo element so that it's behind a link's text. For example;

**HTML**

```
<a href="#">Here's a link</a>
```

**SCSS**

```
a {
    background: #666:
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    position: relative;
    color: #FFF;

    &:before {
        /* this is occupied */
    }

    &:after {
        content: "";
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        top: 0; left: 0;
        background: #000;
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is to display the link's text. This is currently not happening because the `:after` element is overlapping it. I'd like to put the text to the front without using something like a `<span>` tag. Note: it should overlap its original background, but not the text.

Is there a way to achieve this, or is this simply impossible?

Comment: Every element that you want to modify the z-index of need to have a position attribute, mostly "position:absolute". And then move it, you could try that.

Comment: have you tried z-index?

Comment: and why aren't you using background to the content? can you explain why you are doing in such way?

Answer (score 1):

It's as easy as setting the `z-index: -1;` for the `:after` pseudo-element.

```
&:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    z-index: -1; /* Set this */
    background: #000;
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/tm9n0x5g/1/

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment, there is one trick you could use but I don't know if it will go along your animation. You could use a title attribute in the HTML itself and use it as the content of the `:after` pseudo-element.

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  background: #666;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFF;
  z-index: 1;
}
a:after {
  content: attr(title);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #000;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" title="Here's a link">Here's a link</a>
```

Then you can perhaps fade it in/out or whatever you prefer.

Here's a new JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/tm9n0x5g/1/

Comment: Well, that makes it disappear fully. It should be above its original background though, but beneath the text.

Comment: Yeah I just realised that it might be the text you want in front only.

Comment: Can I just ask you why do you even need to do this? Why can't you just alter the background of the `<a>` element itself? Because isn't your solution that you want equivalent of this?

Comment: It's because I'll animate the :after element in. It's just for an animation effect.

Comment: Ok, well can you explain the animation that you want and we can try to make it another easy way because I don't think you can use the z-index in this way.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a possible solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found a proper solution. I'll use a `box-shadow: inset 0 -3.125rem 0 #000;` on the element instead. This way I don't have to use the `:after` element.

Thank you all for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `z-index:-1;` to the `:after`-pseudo

```css
a {
    background: #666:
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    position: relative;
    color: #FFF;
}

a:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  background: #000;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Here's a link</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d8htv6a9/